# Airflow: Does not compile DAGs

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Just recently updated from 1.10.1 to 1.10.4 and noticed that airflow does not create ‘dag.pyc’ files under dag home directory. 
What can cause that?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?